# Java connect to mssql 2008 R2 10.x.x.x address

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'am trying to connect to a MS-SQL 2008 R2 server which is located on a 10.x.x.x address in my network.

My java code looks as follows

```
public void getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.x.x.x:1433/TestTv","username","password");
}
```

But i get an error as follows

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number
>   1433/TestTv is not valid.

I have also tried with port 1443 and same issue. How and where can i check on my 2008 R2 server what port to use? Under **sql server configuration manager** Protocols for SQLEXPRESS TCP/IP port is set to 1443 and the port under **client protocols** is set to 1433.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding `/TestTV` onto the end of the address?  Try it without that.

If TestTV is a SQL instance, the syntax is `jdbc:sqlserver://10.x.x.x\TestTv:1433`

Port 1433 is the standard port.